# Load Javascripts Asynchronously from a Function in Framework

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous

I have a system that uses some frameworks. This framework has a function named `addScript( $path )` and uses this function to load javascripts.

```
public function addScript( $path ){
    $this->_jsFiles[$path] = $path;
}

//Or either this one
public function addScript($script) {
    $this->scripts[md5($script)] = $script;
}
```

How I call the method is below;

```
$helper->addScript( 'javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' );
```

I know how to load javascripts asyn. with using  tag.

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

I am not quite familiar using PHP to load javascripts, is it possible to load scripts asynchronously with using these functions?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think so. you can spread the requests across different subdomains, which will load them in parllel, but to load them in a truly asynchronous way, you'd have to use AJAX.